# Filter duplicate output over consecutive rolling period on Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table with daily regression test results and would like to get an output of tests that fail consecutively in the last 3 days.

The table looks something like this.

```
| ID | rule | status | environment | date        |   note | 
------------------------------------------
| 1  | Test01 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-23  | 
| 2  | Test02 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-23  | 
| 3  | Test03 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-23  | 
| 4  | Test01 | pass | staging     | 2018-05-23  | 
| 5  | Test02 | pass | staging     | 2018-05-23  | 
| 6  | Test03 | pass | staging     | 2018-05-23  | 
| 7  | Test01 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-24  | 
| 8  | Test02 | fail | dev         | 2018-05-24  |  fail note
| 9  | Test03 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-24  | 
| 10 | Test01 | fail | dev         | 2018-05-24  |  fail note
| 11 | Test02 | fail | dev         | 2018-05-24  |  fail note
| 12 | Test03 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-24  | 
| 13 | Test01 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-25  | 
| 14 | Test02 | fail | dev         | 2018-05-25  |  fail note
| 15 | Test03 | fail | dev         | 2018-05-25  |  fail note
| 16 | Test01 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-26  | 
| 17 | Test02 | fail | dev         | 2018-05-26  |  fail note
| 18 | Test03 | pass | dev         | 2018-05-26  |
```

So, assuming today is 2018-05-26 how do I output a result that shows the Test02 has been failing in the last 3 days or ID (rolling period) in Postgres?

The reason why I want it consecutive is because there may be tests that fail one day and pass the next and fail the next due to network issues so having consecutive requirement ensures elimination of that. Additionally there are also duplicate test runs during the same day (so Test01 can run multiple times during the same day potentially)

Comment: I don't get your logic. Why generate a fail note for ID 8? It didn't consecutively fail in the last 3 days. It passed before. The same thing with Test03 ID 15. Or is it just a comment? Is your desired output if today was 2018-05-26 to get Test02? It's ambiguous. Please edit your question and clarify. Also, what about environment? You did not mention if we separate environments as well... but I'd assume so.

Comment: I've followed the logic in your explanation below the sample data and posted my answer.

Comment: the note field is not needed, it just adds some version info when status is not pass. There are 2 environments but they don't need to be in the query at this time, I can filter out if need be.

Answer (score 0):

In respect to current date, you want to look through records that are dating maximum 2 days back from it and show only these rules for which you've found that a test has failed all the times it was done (for each environment separately):

```
select rule, environment
from t
where date > current_date - 3 -- for your sample data it's '2018-05-26'
group by rule, environment
having sum(case when status = 'fail' then 1 end) = count(*)
```

Output for your sample data and `where date > '2018-05-26'::date - 3`:

```
  rule  | environment
--------+-------------
 Test02 | dev
```

Comment: Hrmm is this just counting the fail status? I'm not quite getting the output that I know has been failing day over day

Comment: No, we look at all records for a rule (for example Test02) and based on that we check if within last 3 days there were only fails and none that passed. If there needs to be any clarification, please edit your question with some more information. For this data you've posted it seems ok?